# drupal7 custom form drop down show 0

Tags: forms

I get a problem with my dropdown that shows "--select--","0","foods","meals" when I developing custom form with Drupal 7. The purpose of my dropdown is used to show "foods" and "meals" from category table. How does this "0" come from? I am hoping anyone suggestion to fix it.

```
function subcategory_form($form, &$form_state= NULL, $my_object= '', $subcategoryId, $name, $categoryId) {

     $category = db_select('category', 'cat')
    ->fields('cat')
    ->execute();

    $rows[] = array();
    while($data = $category->fetchAssoc())
    {
        $rows[$data['id']] = t($data['name']);
        dpm($rows);
    }

    $form['category_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Category'),
    '#options' => $rows,
    '#default_value' =>t($categoryId),
    '#description' => t("Please select category."),
    '#required' => 'true'
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the custom code for the select options to be used?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, but you didn't show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes, I just upload my code now, thank for your comment.

Comment: Close vote retracted, now it's OK. And you can see why we require code in such situations, right? Because that's what makes answers possible.

Answer (score 2):

The code `$rows[] = array();` will become a row in the array itself and will not just create an array as you probably want.

Change `$rows[] = array();` to `$rows = array();`

Comment: @PontusNilsson That's not what "closed" means here. Question will stay open, and accept mark will only mean that OP is not in *need* for another answer.

Comment: @Mołot ahh yes you are right, I was thinking of that the question won't show up under unanswered questions but as you say that doesn't mean closed :)